# I am trying to find the prime numbers from 0 to a given number from the user

Tags: java

My code doesn't work and i don't know either why or how to make it work. This is my code.

```
public static void ex5(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int givenNr = scan.nextInt();
    int m = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < givenNr; i++){
             while (m <= i/2 ){
                 if(i % m != 0) {
                     System.out.print(i + " ");
                 }
                 m++;
             }
            }
            }
```

Comment: This logic would not work. even if you put m=1 inside,  basically what you are checking here is that if a given number is not divisible by any number less than its half than it is prime, which is wrong by the definition of prime.
Can you lay some light on what is though process for the code.
first check for base case ie 2, according to this logic it will not be prime because 1 divides 2. build itut from there.

Comment: I will try and think it over. thank you

Comment: You need to look up the Sieve of Eratosthenese. At present all you're print going is the *non*-prime numbers.

Comment: I did just now, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void ex5() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int givenNr = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 2; i < givenNr; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i))
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Terrible idea. You should not call `isPrime()` methods in a loop.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Then how to check if number is prime or not ?. Please let me know so I can learn more. I already used least complexity code to check if number is prime or not.